# Remove inner list in list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am using this code to extract the genres from list of dictionaries.

```
dict=[{'genres': ['Thriller'], 'year': '2014'}, {'genres': ['Animation','Drama'], 'year': '2014'}]
test=[i["genres"] for i in dict]
test
[['Thriller'], ['Animation', 'Drama']]
```

I want to remove the inner list and create single list.

```
Expected output:['Thriller', 'Animation', 'Drama']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to do this:

```
>>> list_of_dicts =[{'genres': ['Thriller'], 'year': '2014'}, {'genres': ['Animation','Drama'], 'year': '2014'}]
>>> [genre for d in list_of_dicts for genre in d['genres']]
['Thriller', 'Animation', 'Drama']
```

In case you have possible repeats, call set over this

```
>>> set(genre for d in list_of_dicts for genre in d['genres'])
{'Animation', 'Drama', 'Thriller'}
```

Taking cue from @mgilson's answer, if you want this to work with dicts which don't have the `genres` key, you can do

```
>>> list_of_dicts =[{'genres': ['Thriller'], 'year': '2014'}, {"year": '2014'}]
>>> set(genre for d in list_of_dicts for genre in d.get('genres', []))
{'Thriller'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `itertools`.

First, write a generator that yields the genres lists (one after another).

```
import itertools
dicts = [{'genres': ['Thriller'], 'year': '2014'}, {'genres': ['Animation','Drama'], 'year': '2014'}]
genres_nested = (dct.get('genres', ()) for dct in dicts)
```

This particular generator is "forgiving" -- It'll allow for dicts in the list that don't have a `'genres'` field.

Then, flatten that nested structure with `itertools.chain.from_iterable` (you could use a nested comprehension -- but I've always found `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to be easier to read ...):

```
genres = itertools.chain.from_iterable(genres_nested)
```

If you need a list, you can always call `list` on the resulting "chain" object...

```
print(list(genres))
```

And as a side benefit, other than this last stage, everything we've done was completely lazy -- No intermediate lists wasting storage on our computers.  Yeah!

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension is your friend

```
>>> dicts=[{'genres': ['Thriller'], 'year': '2014'}, {'genres': ['Animation','Drama'], 'year': '2014'}]
>>> [gen for d in dicts for gen in d['genres']]
['Thriller', 'Animation', 'Drama']
```